# Y a-t-il une différence audible entre « il mange » et « ils mangent » ?

Tags: prononciation, pluriel, conjugaison

Phrases exemples:

> Ils mangent de la nourriture.
>   Il mange de la nourriture.

Les deux sonnent pareil pour moi quand j'écoute la voix de l'ordinateur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il n'y a aucune différence, les deux sont prononcés de manière rigoureusement identique. C'est vrai quel que soit le niveau de langue (au moins en France ; je pense que c'est le cas dans tous les dialectes du français mais je ne peux pas l'affirmer avec certitude).

Le seul moyen de distinguer « il mange » de « ils mangent » à l'oral est de faire une liaison, par exemple de prononcer « ils mangent en marchant » [il.mɑ̃(.)ʒ(ə).t‿ɑ̃.maʁ.ʃɑ̃] (il/manj/ten/mar/chan ou il/man/je/ten/mar/chan). Même dans une telle phrase, si on ne fait pas la liaison, la phrase reste ambigue, parce que cette liaison après un verbe est facultative et rare.

Au passage, dans la tournure interrogative « mangent-ils ? », on fait toujours la liaison ; mais comme au singulier on introduit un [t euphonique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=t+euphonique&T3.x=12&T3.y=11) « mange-t-il ? », la prononciation du singulier et du pluriel est aussi identique.

Si on a besoin de préciser à l'oral, il faut préciser à qui le pronom se réfère. En langue familière, on peut répéter le pronom (ce qui, de manière générale, est un moyen de mettre l'accent sur le pronom, et d'opposer la ou les personnes concernées à d'autres) : « lui, il mange » ou « eux, ils mangent ».